# How to check if a data from an API is in an elasticsearch index using python, and, if it isn't, insert it

Tags: python, elasticsearch, openweathermap

I would to retrive some data from the Open Weather Map API and insert them into an Elasticsearch index with Python. Then I would take some new ones and check if they are already in the index. If they are not, I would add them in the index. If they are already in it, they should be ignored.

```
import datetime
from pprint import pprint
import requests
import urllib
import json
import request
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch import helpers
import time

es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}])
r = requests.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=###').json()
pprint(r)

res = es.search(index="weathermap", body={"query": {"match_all": {}}})

for m in res:
   if m not in res:
      es.index(index='weathermap', doc_type='doc')
```

Comment: Ciao Eddie,  how you define if a document is already in the index? Which fields are unique, only the combination of timestamp and the city?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking if it exists and adding it if it doesn't, you could let Elastic do all of that for you. Instead of using `es.index(...)` you can call `es.create(...)` as specified in the documentation for [create](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html?highlight=create#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.create).

> Adds a typed JSON document in a specific index, making it searchable.
>   Behind the scenes this method calls index(…, op_type=’create’)

From the [Elastic documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#operation-type):

> The index operation also accepts an `op_type` that can be used to force
>   a `create` operation, allowing for "put-if-absent" behavior. When `create`
>   is used, the index operation will fail if a document by that id
>   already exists in the index.

So it will throw an error if it doesn't insert, so be sure to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use following code

```
import datetime
from pprint import pprint
import requests
import urllib
import json
import request
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch import helpers
import time

es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}])
r = requests.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=###').json()
pprint(r)

res = es.search(index="weathermap", body={"query": {"match_all": {}}})

for m in res['hits']['hits']:
   if search_value not in res:
      es.index(index='weathermap', doc_type='doc',whole_doc_body)
```